# Merging tables to get the permutations of the rows - access

Tags: ms-access

New to access and the site but I've learned a lot from here already. Hoping that this is a fairly easy question to answer.

I've got 2 tables of data and I'm trying to get all the possible permutations with the rows intact.

I have:

Table Day 1

```
Start    Finish
A.         B
B.         C
C.         D
D.         A
```

Table Day 2

```
Start.    Finish
B.          D
C.          A
D.          B
A.          C
```

What I want to generate is a table or query that combines the possible permutations of Day 1 and Day 2 to get a new start and finish:

Table Day1&2

```
Start.   Finish 
A.         D
B.         A
C.         B
Etc.      Etc
```

Answer (score 0):

That could be a *Cartesian* query:

```sql
Select Distinct A.Start, B.Finish
From A, B
Where A.Start <> B.Finish
```